# É correto afirmar que esta simplificação booleana está correta?

Tags: sistemas-digitais, circuitos-lógicos, álgebra-booleana

Possuímos a seguinte **tabela verdade**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo a partir dos **mintermos** a sua **expressão booleana** é a seguinte:

```
A'.B'.C' + A'.B'.C + A'.B.C + A.B.C' + A.B.C
```

De acordo com [este site](http://www.32x8.com), diz-se que a **simplificação** de sua **expressão** é dada por:

```
y = A'.B' + A'.C + A.B
```

Porém com a minha **simplificação booleana** eu consegui chegar no seguinte resultado:

```
S = A'.B'.C' + A'.B'.C + A'.B.C + A.B.C' + A.B.C
S = A’.B’(C’ + C) + A’.B.C + AB(C’ + C)
S = A’.B’ + A’.B.C + AB
S = A’.B’ + B(A’.C + A)
S = A’.B’ + B(C.1)
S = A’.B’ + BC
```

**Conferindo no** [seguinte site](http://brinks.guisehn.com/tabela-vdd/), **para as duas respostas eu não consegui a mesma saída da tabela verdade.. Não sou doutor para poder comprovar e afirmar que está correto e esta seria a melhor solução, porém que conclusão eu devo tirar disto?**

- **a) Que a minha simplificação está correta, mesmo diferente da outra?**
- **b) Que a minha simplificação é melhor que a outra, por utilizar menos portas?**

Comment: O primeiro link está quebrado!

Comment: Como você chegou na sua simplificação? E você tem certeza que está correto a expressão dada pelo site? Não seria y = A'.B' + A'.B.C + A.B

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino alterei o link e adicionei a minha solução!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um erro na sua solução ao apontar que:

```
S = A’.B’ + B(A’.C + A)
S = A’.B’ + B(C.1)
```

Você está implicando que A'.C + A = 1 = (A' + A)

```
A   C   C.(A'+A)
0   0      0
0   1      1
1   0      0
1   1      1

A   C   A'.C+A 
0   0     0
0   1     1
1   0     1
1   1     1
```

Vale notar que A'.B' + A'.B.C + A.B também é solução. Mas de alguma maneira, A'.B' + A'.C + A.B também é.

Comment: Eu falei que A’.C + A = 1, fazendo o seguinte: C.A’ + A, onde no apostolado A’ + A = 1, portando C.1 = C.. Isto está errado de se fazer? E o porque está errado?

Comment: A' + A = 1 está correto. No entanto, C.A' + A não se encaixa nesse postulado, tem um termo C multiplicando A' ali. Se fosse C.A' + C.A = C.(A' + A) dai poderia.

Comment: Então eu nunca posso fazer isso quando é uma Multiplicação lógica e uma Soma lógica, somente se X e Y fosse uma multiplicação lógica, ou seja, para manipular AND E OR, somente com o postulado o qual informou acima, se fosse um fator comum correto?  A última pergunta é: se a tabela verdade fossem iguais, eu teria uma solução correta e melhor do que as outras ?

Answer (score 0):

**Resposta as suas perguntas imediatas:**
a)--- minha simplificação está correta, mesmo diferente da outra?
     Sua simplificação está errada a partir da linha 4 (linha que inicia sua implicação A’.C + A = C . 1). Ser diferente da outra não implica necessariamente estar errada.

b)--- minha simplificação é melhor que a outra, por utilizar menos portas?
    Se sua resposta estivesse correta, sim e sua maior melhoria seria por não usar uma porta OR de três entradas e sim uma porta OR com duas entradas.

**Passo a Passo:**

Inclui alguns passos que você omitiu, assim como pontos '.' em lugares como AB, de maneira a ficar, A.B, para não deixar nada implícito. Os comentários ao lado de uma linha dizem respeito a oque eu tive que fazer nessa linha para chegar a próxima linha.

Obs. Recomendo não usar o ponto '.' para representar a operação lógica AND assim como o "+" para o OR, isso sobrecarrega esses operadores quando você estiver fazendo aritmética. Recomendo usar o "^" para o  AND e "v" para o OR. Para não confundi-lo fiz seguindo sua maneira ;)

```
1. S = A'.B'.C' + A'.B'.C + A'.B.C + A.B.C' + A.B.C  /* distributiva AND */

2. S = A’.B’.(C’ + C) + A’.B.C + A.B.(C’ + C)        /* elemento máximo OR */

3. S = A’.B’.1  + A’.B.C + A.B.1  (OMITIDO)          /* elemento neutro AND */

4. S = A’.B’ + A’.B.C + A.B                          /* associativa AND */ 

5. S = A’.B’ + B.A’.C + B.A   (OMITIDO)              /* distributiva AND */ 

6. S = A’.B’ + B(A’.C + A)                           /* por (1) */

S = A’.B’ + B(C.1)                                   /* ERRADO */
S = A’.B’ + BC                                       /* ERRADO */

7. S = A’.B’ + B.(A + C)                             /* distributiva AND */ 

8. S = A’.B’ + B.A  + B.C  /* e isso é equivalente a resposta do site por (2) */
```

**Justificativas**

***(1)*** Prova: A'.C + A = A + C

```
A’.C + A                   /* associativa OR  */
A + A’.C                   /* distributiva OR     */
(A + A') . (A + C)         /* elemento máximo OR  */
1 . (A + C)                /* elemento neutro AND */
A + C
```

Portanto,
    A'.C + A = A + C

Prova pela tabela verdade:

(Para acompanhar a prova pela tabela verdade recomendo abrir a imagem em uma aba separada)

Como há 2 variáveis, A e C, 2^2  combinações = 4 combinações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Passo 1, 
        Lado esquerdo,
             A Coluna(Col.) 3  recebe NEGAÇÃO da Col. 1.
             Col. 5 recebe Col.2;
             Col. 7 recebe Col.1 

        Lado direito,
             Col. 9 recebe Col. 1;
             Col. 11 recebe Col. 2


Passo 2,
        Lado esquerdo: Col. 4 recebe AND entre a Col. 3 e 5.

        Lado direito: Col. 10 recebe OR entre a Col. 9 e 11.

Passo 3, 
        Lado esquerdo: Col. 6 recebe OR entre a Col. 4 e 7.

Passo 4,(sinal de igual, nesse caso, representa o operador de equivalência)
        Pela definição de equivalência, as colunas 6 e 10 deveriam ser iguais,
        fato que acontece. Portanto, está provada a equivalência entre as funções lógicas.
```

***(2)*** Prova: A’.B’ + B.A  + B.C = A'.B' + A'.C + A.B

Prova pela tabela verdade:

3 variáveis A, B, C. 2^3 combinações = 8 combinações

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Passo 1, 
        Lado esquerdo,
             Col. 4 recebe a NEGAÇÃO da Col. 1
             Col. 6 recebe a NEGAÇÃO da Col. 2
             Col. 8 e 12 recebe Col. 2
             Col. 10 recebe Col. 1
             Col. 14 recebe Col. 3

        Lado direito,
             Col. 16 e Col. 20 recebem a NEGAÇÃO da Col. 1
             Col. 18 recebe a NEGAÇÃO da Col. 2
             Col. 22 recebe Col. 3
             Col. 24 recebe Col. 1
             Col. 26 recebe Col. 2 

 Passo 2, 
         Lado esquerdo,
              Col. 5 recebe AND entre Col. 4 e 6;
              Col. 9 recebe AND entre Col. 8 e 10;
              Col. 13 recebe AND entre Col. 12 e 14;

         Lado direito,
              Col. 17 recebe AND entre Col. 16 e 18;
              Col. 21 recebe AND entre Col. 20 e 22;
              Col. 25 recebe AND entre Col. 24 e 26;

 Passo 3, (Lembre-se que o OR é associativo)
         Lado esquerdo, 
              Col. 7 recebe OR entre Col. 5 e 9;

         Lado direito, 
              Col. 19 recebe OR entre Col. 17 e 21;

 Passo 4, 
         Lado esquerdo, 
              Col. 11 recebe OR entre Col. 7 e Col. 13

         Lado direito, 
              Col. 23 recebe OR entre Col. 19 e 25;

 Passo 5,
         Pela definição de equivalência 11 deveria ser igual a 23, 
         fato que acontece. Portanto, está provada a equivalência 
         entre essas duas funções lógicas.
```

**Complementar**

(1) Sobre a resposta do Gabriel, ele errou ao falar que você implicou que A'.C + A = 1, você não fez isso, oque você fez for implicar que A'.C + A = C.

(2) O motivo pelo qual há várias soluções é que de fato não existe uma única solução correta. Mas não se engane, como foi citado pelo Guilherme A'.B' + A'.B.C + A.B também é uma solução porém não é uma "solução correta", ao meu ver, porque ainda pode ser simplificada.

Para esse problema existem duas soluções corretas. O mapa de karnaugh justifica.

Primeira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segunda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seja *f* a função representada por esses mapas de Karnaugh então : (Primeira Imagem) f = A'.B' + A'.C + A.B ou (Segunda Imagem) f = A'.B' + B.C + A.B , respectivamente a resposta que você encontrou no site e a resposta que encontramos.